# Integrating React Js with AEM CMS (Adobe Experience Manager CMS)

Tags: reactjs, aem

I am trying to integrate react js application into existing AEM CMS application and below is the way how i am trying to put the values in setting for AEM CMS

[image]

And below is the configuration generated by CMS in div :

```
<div data-t-name="CustomComponent"
data-css="xxx/styles/main.css"
data-js="xxx/main.js">
    <div
id="xxxx"
data-application-name="xxx" data-config='
{
  "ID": "bb70cfde887ba7157a2dec3ff1d539ea40d817d97ad270278ba982008f918f96",
  "EMBEDDED": true,
  "LOCALE": "en",
  "organizationId": "xxx",
  "eventId": "xxx"
}'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Issue is when i try to put css and js referance as entry point into above setting below is error i have received , any one please guide or clues to sort this issue

[image]

Please find the webpack config below :

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const project = require('../project.config');

const inProject = path.resolve.bind(path, project.basePath);
const inProjectSrc = (file) => inProject(project.srcDir, file);

const __DEV__ = project.env === 'development';
const __TEST__ = project.env === 'test';
const __PROD__ = project.env === 'production';

const config = {
  entry: {
    normalize: [
      inProjectSrc('normalize'),
    ],
    main: [
      inProjectSrc(project.main),
    ],
  },
  devtool: project.sourcemaps ? 'source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: inProject(project.outDir),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: project.publicPath,
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      inProject(project.srcDir),
      'node_modules',
    ],
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
  externals: project.externals,
  module: {
    rules: [],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(Object.assign({
      'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(project.env) },
      __DEV__,
      __TEST__,
      __PROD__,
    }, project.globals)),
  ],
};

// JavaScript
// ------------------------------------
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      plugins: [
        'babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy',
        'babel-plugin-transform-class-properties',
        'babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
        [
          'babel-plugin-transform-runtime',
          {
            helpers: true,
            polyfill: false, // we polyfill needed features in src/normalize.js
            regenerator: true,
          },
        ],
        [
          'babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread',
          {
            useBuiltIns: true, // we polyfill Object.assign in src/normalize.js
          },
        ],
      ],
      presets: [
        'babel-preset-react',
        ['babel-preset-env', {
          modules: false,
          targets: {
            ie9: true,
          },
          uglify: true,
        }],
      ],
    },
  }],
});

// Styles
// ------------------------------------
const extractStyles = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'styles/[name].css',
  allChunks: true,
  disable: __DEV__,
});

config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
  loader: extractStyles.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: project.sourcemaps,
          minimize: {
            autoprefixer: {
              add: true,
              remove: true,
              browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            },
            discardComments: {
              removeAll: true,
            },
            discardUnused: false,
            mergeIdents: false,
            reduceIdents: false,
            safe: true,
            sourcemap: project.sourcemaps,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: project.sourcemaps,
          includePaths: [
            inProjectSrc('styles'),
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  }),
});
config.plugins.push(extractStyles);

// Images
// ------------------------------------
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|JPG|)$/,
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options: {
    limit: 8192,
  },
})

// Fonts
// ------------------------------------
;[
  ['woff', 'application/font-woff'],
  ['woff2', 'application/font-woff2'],
  ['otf', 'font/opentype'],
  ['ttf', 'application/octet-stream'],
  ['eot', 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject'],
  ['svg', 'image/svg+xml'],
].forEach((font) => {
  const extension = font[0];
  const mimetype = font[1];

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: new RegExp(`\\.${extension}$`),
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
      limit: 10000,
      mimetype,
    },
  });
});

// HTML Template
// ------------------------------------
config.plugins.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: inProjectSrc('index.html'),
  inject: true,
  minify: {
    collapseWhitespace: true,
  },
}));

// Development Tools
// ------------------------------------
if (__DEV__) {
  config.entry.main.push(
    `webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?path=${config.output.publicPath}__webpack_hmr`
  );
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
  );
}

// Bundle Splitting
// ------------------------------------
if (!__TEST__) {
  const bundles = ['normalize', 'manifest'];

  if (project.vendors && project.vendors.length) {
    bundles.unshift('vendor');
    config.entry.vendor = project.vendors;
  }
  config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ names: bundles }));
}

// Production Optimizations
// ------------------------------------
if (__PROD__) {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: false,
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: !!config.devtool,
      comments: false,
      compress: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true,
        conditionals: true,
        unused: true,
        comparisons: true,
        sequences: true,
        dead_code: true,
        evaluate: true,
        if_return: true,
        join_vars: true,
      },
    })
  );
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: @KarunKamal my configuration of webpack is different than that provide above please refer my webpack configuration

Comment: @KarunKamal can you please see my webpack config and point me is that possible to use the solution provided by you?